# Finding most searched words with a keyword!

Tags: windows

Is it possible to create a script that can find the top 100 words searched in Google along with a given keyword?

example: If the given keyword is "script", then the script would give the top 100 words searched in Google with the word "script":

```
 html script
 script tag
 free script
 script language
 script magazine
```

I need this script to help my visitors to know what are the best words to use as domain name.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about Windows tool, but there is a tool online which provides you with the similar keywords searched by users... i.e Google Adwords Keyword Planner...

Steps to get similar keywords :

- Go to [Google Adwords](https://adwords.google.com/)
- Login and go to https://adwords.google.com/ko/KeywordPlanner or from the top menu, select 
  *Tools* -> *Keyword Planner*
- After you login, you'll get four types of options which will fetch you the data using different parameters like

  - Search for new keyword and ad group ideas
  - Get search volume for a list of keywords or group them into ad groups
  - Get traffic estimates for a list of keywords
  - Multiply keyword lists to get new keyword ideas

According to me, the best option fits for your requirements is *Search for new keyword and ad group ideas*, which is the first option, say your client wants information for keywords related to cars, so open the tool, type the word *Cars* in the box and than you will get two tabs, which says

- Ad group Ideas
- Keyword Ideas

So the second tab is what you are looking for...

[image]

---

Now am getting a keyword with my country name because I've set the filters accordingly, you can customize them from the left hand panel...

[image]

Comment: How can I get all those details in my website without going everytime to google adwords. Are there a way to extract those information to my website via a php code or script? what I need is to type my keyword in a search box in MY website, and then get those details that adwords planner provides!!

Comment: @Faouzi They would be having API by which you can extract the info